# Taylor expanssion to the order 2

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $\alpha>0$. we considere the sequance

$$a_n=\frac{(\ln(1+1/n))^{\alpha}}{(\ln(n))^{\alpha}}$$

Could you please help me to give the Taylor expansion of $a_n$ to the order 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to find a taylor series for a given function, [general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition)?

Comment: yes, this is what I started to write $$\ln(1+1/n)=1/n+1/n^2+o(1/n^3)$$

and $$(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$$ but I don't know how to continue

Comment: So you have problems in differentiating?

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi, Please take a look at my edited comment

Comment: Why did you expand $\ln(1+1/n)$ and $(1+x)^{\alpha}$...If you need the expansion of $(f(x))^{\alpha}$ would you expand f(x) seperately and then apply the power on an infinite sequence or would you consider $h(x)=f(x)^{\alpha}$ and find the Taylor series for h(x)?